# Routing of backend and frontend in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, routes, frontend, backend

At the moment I try to change some links im my current project.

These are two examples.

```
xyz.com/mn-op (example for user site) [old one xyz.com/user/mn-op]
xyz.com/backend (site for backend)
```

If I want to open the site for the backend then I get the following error.

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
No query results for model [App\Models\User].
```

Following is my folder structure at my project.

```
laravel
-app
--Http
---Controllers
----Frontend
----Backend
```

This is a part of my routes.php.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'frontend'], function () {
    Route::get('{username?}', ['uses' => 'UserController@getProfile', 'as' => 'user.profile']);
    });
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'backend'], function() {
        Route::get('backend', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@getIndex', 'as' => 'backend']);
    });
});
```

How can I fix it so that I can open my backend again?

Comment: Well, there are no users found. Maybe you should post your User.php and your UserController

Comment: I don't understand why I should to post it, if I have the issue at the backend. At the usercontroller is everything running.

Comment: You are trying to retrieve specific user, where the id does not exist.

Comment: This I can see but in the source code of the Dashboard Controller is nothing inserted with Users.